# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I using Spring + Hibernate + JPA and Tomcat 7 for REST service. When I start the app I get the following:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carService': Error creating bean with name 'carServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carDao': Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carDao': Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carDao': Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

Below i show my spring config class

```
@Configuration
@Import(DispatcherServletConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.parkingTracker.controller, org.parkingTracker.service, org.parkingTracker.dao")
@ImportResource("classpath*:/dao/src/main/resources/spring/dao-context.xml")
public class RootConfig {
    public RootConfig() {}
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.parkingTracker.controller, org.parkingTracker.service")
public class DispatcherServletConfig {
    public DispatcherServletConfig() {}
}
```

I also have service and dao classes for access to data. To inject EntityManager in my dao i am using `@PersistenceContext` annotation, for inject dao for service  class i am using simple spring annotations. Below you can see my spring xml config for DAO layout. **One important comments, when i run test for dao classes all passing right, and i don't have any Exceptions, and i am obtaining valid data**

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd ">
<context:component-scan base-package="org.parkingTracker.dao"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/parking"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="a1f10g"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
</bean>
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.parkingTracker.model"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<jpa:repositories  base-package="org.parkingTracker"
                   entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                   transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/></beans>
```

CarServiceImpl:

```
 public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {
@Autowired
private CarDao carDao;
@Override
public void saveCar(Car car) throws EntityAlreadyExistException {
    carDao.saveCar(car);
}
@Override
public Car getCarById(int id) {
    return carDao.getCarById(id);
}
@Override
public Car getCarByIdWithTimeSpend(int id) {
    return carDao.getCarByIdWithTimeSpend(id);
}
@Override
public Car getCarByNumber(String number) {
    return carDao.getCarByNumber(number);
}
@Override
public Car getCarByNumberWithTimeSpend(String number) {
    return carDao.getCarByNumberWithTimeSpend(number);
}
```

CarDao:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("carDao")
public class CarDaoImp implements CarDao{
    private final String EXIST_SQL = "SELECT 1 FROM car WHERE car_num = :num";
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Transactional()
    public void saveCar(Car car) throws EntityAlreadyExistException {
        if(entityManager.createNativeQuery(EXIST_SQL).setParameter("num", car.getNumber()).getSingleResult()!=null){
            throw new  EntityAlreadyExistException();
        }else {
            entityManager.persist(car);
        }
    } 
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Car getCarById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Car getCarByIdWithTimeSpend(int id) {
        Car car = entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(car.getTimeSet());
        return car;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Car getCarByNumber(String number) throws NoResultException{
        CriteriaBuilder builder  = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> carCriteriaQuery = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Car.class);
        Root<Car> root = carCriteriaQuery.from(Car.class);
        carCriteriaQuery.select(root);
        carCriteriaQuery.where(builder.equal( root.get(Car_.number), number ));
        return entityManager.createQuery(carCriteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Car getCarByNumberWithTimeSpend(String number){
        CriteriaBuilder builder  = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> carCriteriaQuery = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Car.class);
        Root<Car> root = carCriteriaQuery.from(Car.class);
        carCriteriaQuery.select(root);
        carCriteriaQuery.where(builder.equal( root.get(Car_.number), number ));
        Car car = entityManager.createQuery(carCriteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
        Hibernate.initialize(car.getTimeSet());
        return car;
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.parkingTracker.controller.config.RootConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.parkingTracker.controller.config.DispatcherServletConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I very much doubt that you have a package `dao.src.main.resources.spring` where your XML files are stored. It probably should be `classpath*:spring/dao-context.xml`. But why do you use XML rather than Java code to define your configuration?

Comment: I also tried to put my dao-context.xml in root folder, and i had same errors, and if spring cant find config his throws another exceptionl like FileNotFound

Comment: can  you add your carServiceImpl

Comment: @kuhajeyan just added

Comment: and cardao would also help

Comment: @kuhajeyan done and added web.xml too

Comment: I see the EntityManager bean id is `emf`, but the name using in your dao is entityManager. I suspect maybe it's the reason the error occurs.   Ref: https://spring.io/blog/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring

Comment: seems all good to me, leads me thing your dao-context.xml location could be the only problem. can you move your dao-context.xml to resource root and change to @ImportResource("classpath:/dao-context.xml") and try

Comment: @artificerPi But my test for carDao runs correctly

Comment: @kuhajeyan i did this before, and i have same errors,

Comment: resource location could be correct for your test class environtment but not for application  ie. ( test/src/resources, src/main/resource for applicaiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IOC container is failing to inject the `EntityManagerFactory`
to `CarDaoImp`. I looked at your code and it seems that you defined all the necessary configurations,  I think the problem lies down with your XML configuration file loading.

Try to use `classpath:your_xml_config.xml`, with out the folder structure prefix. like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DispatcherServletConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.parkingTracker.controller, org.parkingTracker.service, org.parkingTracker.dao")
@ImportResource("classpath:dao-context.xml")
public class RootConfig {
    public RootConfig() {}
}
```

Comment: I added dao-context.xml, to root folders and i have FIleNotFoundException when `@ImportResource("classpath:dao-context.xml")`  and when i write `@ImportResource("classpath*:/dao-context.xml")` i have same errors

Comment: The `dao-context.xml` should be placed under the `/resources` folder, what is your project file structure?

Comment: thank you, i just put my context in resources folders